# Excel formula to return value instead of TRUE or False

Tags: excel, excel-formula, match, string-matching, formulas

I am very newbie in excel, I wanted to make my formula to return matched value instead of TRUE/FALSE

```
=NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B2))))))
```

is there anyway this formula can be revised to return like for example: found word "wow" and return the word into the cell instead of TRUE/FALSE?

thank you

Answer (score 0):

You can use IF function:

```
=IF(logical_test, CONCAT("Found word", $YourWord), "Not found")
```

Comment: I am not following on how to join this into my current formula?

Comment: I am testing this =IF(NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B2)))))), CONCAT("Found word", $YourWord), "Not found")

Comment: $YourWord is the cell of your word...

logical_test will be your formula

Comment: hmm its not working on my end : =IF(NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B3)))))); CONCAT("Found word";B3); "Not found")

Comment: yes if its just {=NOT(NOT(SUM(--NOT(ISERR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21;$B2))))))} it worked and inputted as ranged, using ctrl + shift + space

Comment: I am willing to add in $20 for getting this done as its quite urgent :)

Comment: Use MATCH instead of SEARCH:
=IF(MATCH($B2;$D$2:$D$21)>0; CONCAT("Found " , $B2); CONCAT("Not found ", $B2)). This will search word in $B2 in $D$2:$D$21

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/142813/discussion-between-boby-and-niknik).

Answer (score 0):

Use the `=IF` function.

`=IF(condition; value if true; value if false)`

- `condition` is your condition to test. For example `$A$1 < 5`
- `value if true` is a value returned if condition is true
- `value if false` opposite to previous part, this is a value returned if condition is false.

Following formula will return a `$A$1` cell value if less than 5 and `too big` literally if `$A$1`'s value is bigger or equal to 5:

`=IF($A$1<5; $A$1; "too big")`

Just combine it with your condition.

Answer (score 0):

This will help You Remember the "**`Text`**" must be in **`" "`**

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH(substring;"WOW")); "Yes"; "No")
```

The Value will be only Yes or No , You may change that

Answer (score 0):

There are two cases and I'm not sure which one you need

(1) You have a word like WOW, and you want to find matches in a list of strings like BOWWOW

(2) You have a word like WOW, and you want to find matches for part of it in a list of substrings like OW

The easiest way to do the first one is to use MATCH with a wildcard

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$21,MATCH("*"&B2&"*",$D$2:$D$21,0))
```

For the second one you would need to modify your formula a bit

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$21,MATCH(0,(ISERROR(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21,$B$2))+($D$2:$D$21="")),0))
```

or

```
=INDEX($D$2:$D$21,MATCH(1,ISNUMBER(SEARCH($D$2:$D$21,$B$2))*($D$2:$D$21<>""),0))
```

the last two entered as array formulae using <kbd>Ctrl</kbd><kbd>Shift</kbd><kbd>Enter</kbd>

[image]

Comment: tested the formula, if the column is empty it returned the $D$2 word, and if it's found, its returning the $D$2 word too, instead for example it should have returned $D$4 string

Comment: You are right, I will put in the corrected formulae.

Comment: the string that is being search consists of "string 1|string 2|string 3" matched with for example in the D2 column is "string 2" so that means it can not do a match, but more of find string?

Comment: OK can you add some examples to your question please then we can get a better idea of what you need and can test it properly

Answer (score -1):

I think those semi-colons should be commas?

Comment: Was this intended as answer to the question,or a comment on one of the other answers?  If the latter, please delete this as the answer section is not appropriate for comments.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. Once you have sufficient [reputation](https://stackoverflow.com/help/whats-reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](https://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/comment); instead, [provide answers that don't require clarification from the asker](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/214173/why-do-i-need-50-reputation-to-comment-what-can-i-do-instead). - [From Review](/review/late-answers/35364256)